# Count number of votes each entry gets from user input and output this at the end

Tags: python-3.x

I need to get recurring input from a user (votes) which is terminated by DONE. Once they've entered the votes I need to list the votes and show the number of times each "person" got next to it.

I've managed to do most of it, but I'm struggling to output the unique words and their respective votes. What I've also managed to do so far is create three lists; the first being a list of the unique words, the second - a list of the number of votes each "person" got, and lastly a list of all the inputs. I feel like I'm so close to getting the right output, but I just can't seem to figure out what else I can try.

```
print("Votes counts:")
print()
for r in uniquelist:
    for w in numvotes:
        print("%-10s" % r,"-",w)
```

This prints out the voters, but they're printed out multiple times, while I only want them printed out once. However, the number of votes prints in the correct order, but repeats.

This is what it spits out:

```
Vote counts:
apples     - 2
apples     - 5
apples     - 1
apples     - 2
apples     - 1
oranges    - 2
oranges    - 5
oranges    - 1
oranges    - 2
oranges    - 1
pears      - 2
pears      - 5
pears      - 1
pears      - 2
pears      - 1
bananas    - 2
bananas    - 5
bananas    - 1
bananas    - 2
bananas    - 1
kiwis      - 2
kiwis      - 5
kiwis      - 1
kiwis      - 2
kiwis      - 1
```

While all I want is:

```
Vote counts:
apples - 2
bananas - 2
kiwis - 1
oranges - 5
pears -  1
```

I'm also not sure how to get an order like this or where it comes from logically. It has something to do with the "default order of the sorted function".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you be specific which values needs to be chosen among uniquelist and numvotes. Is it possible for you to post uniquelist & numvotes data.

Answer (score 0):

You have a pair of lists of the same length.
To visit corresponding entries pairwise, use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
    for r, w in zip(uniquelist, numvotes):
        print(r, w)
```

(Or keep using the same fancy formatting when printing.)

As a separate matter, you would like to visit those tuples in [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) order.
Easily done:

```
    for r, w in sorted(zip(uniquelist, numvotes)):
```